# React function not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a simple function that tests the flags on the user's account, but the return statements inside the function are not rendering on screen. The console will read out 2 `GOT HERE`s, but nothing appears under Notifications header.

I have implemented a very similar function on another part of the site, so I am a bit confused on how this function doesn't render as intended?

**Dashboard.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/Fire.js';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.checkFlags = this.checkFlags.bind(this);
      } 

    componentDidMount(){
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
        if (user) {   
            //Grab user flags
            var userFlags = []
            fire.database().ref('/users/' + fire.auth().currentUser.uid + '/flags').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                    userFlags.push({ key: data.key , val: data.val() });
                });
            });

            this.setState({
                userFlags: userFlags
            })          
            }
        });
    }

checkFlags(){
        if(this.state.userFlags){
            this.state.userFlags.map((flag) => {
                if(flag.val === true){
                    if(flag.key === "unverifiedEmail"){
                        console.log("GOT HERE")
                        return(
                            <span>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button 
                                            className="s-btn-inv"
                                            onClick={this.verifyEmail}>
                                            Send verification email</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                        )
                    } else {
                        return(<span>Loading flags...</span>)
                    }   
                } else {
                    return(<span>No notifications at this time!</span>)     
                }
            })
        } else {
            return(<span>Loading notifications...</span>) 
        }
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <hr/>
                <h3>Notifications:</h3>
                { this.checkFlags() }
            </div>
          )
         }
}
export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

**Fire.js:**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';

const DB_CONFIG = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
  };

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);

const storage = firebase.storage()

export {
  storage, fire as default
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `map` function does not return anything. So no elements will be returned from your `checkFlags` function. Add return here:

```
return this.state.userFlags.map((flag) => {
```

Just be aware that this returns an array of results. So seeing as `GOT HERE` was logged twice, your return would be `[<span/>, <span/>]`